# How to derive this mathematical equation from the perspective of the mean-variance portfolio optimization?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, finance-mathematics, modern-portfolio-theory

## Question

- I found a simplified inequation to decide whether the new asset A should be added to my current portfolio B. If the following inequation is satisfied, the new asset A should be added to my portfolio. (source: Mackenzie Investment's research report [Correlation vs. Beta: What is the difference](https://www.mackenzieinvestments.com/content/dam/final/corporate/mackenzie/docs/investment-teams/multi-asset-team/en/Correlation%20vs.%20Beta_%20What%20is%20The%20Difference%20and%20Why%20Does%20It%20Matter_%20_%20Mackenzie%20Investments.pdf))

$$\frac{E(R_{a})}{\sigma_{a}} > \frac{E(R_{b})}{\sigma_{b}} \times corr(R_{a}, R_{b})$$

- One colleague of mine suggested to me that the inequation shown above seems to be derived from the mathematical equation written below, when the condition $W_{a}> 0$ is satisfied.

[image]

- $W_{a}$: how much percentage of my total wealth is invested in the asset A 
  $E(R_{a})$: the expected return of the asset A 
  $\sigma_{a}$: the standard deviation of the returns of the asset A
  $r_{f}$: risk-free return such as the US government bonds
  *I assume that $R_{A}$ is the same thing as $R_{a}$, which means the return of the asset A*.
- Is there anyone who can show me how the equation written at the bottom can be simplified to the inequation written at the top, when the condition $W_{a}> 0$ is satisfied?

Comment: Assume the denominator to be>0, set $r_f=0$

Comment: @Kermittfrog How can we be sure that the denominator is greater than 0? Is there a mathematical formula to guarantee this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that the denominator is positive (ie. $>0$) and let $r_f=0$. For ease of notation, we will rewrite $W_A$ as:

\begin{align*}
W_A = \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[R_A\right] \sigma_B^2 - \mathbb{E}\left[R_B\right]\sigma_A\sigma_B \mathbb{C}orr(R_A, R_B)}{\mathbb{E}\left[R_A\right] \left(\sigma^2_B - \sigma_A\sigma_B \mathbb{C}orr(R_A, R_B)\right)+\mathbb{E}\left[R_B\right]\left(\sigma^2_A - \sigma_A\sigma_B \mathbb{C}orr(R_A, R_B)\right)} = \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[R_A\right] \sigma_B^2 - \mathbb{E}\left[R_B\right]\sigma_A\sigma_B \mathbb{C}orr(R_A, R_B)}{Z_A + Z_B}>0,\\
\end{align*}
Now, adding the negative part of the fraction on both sides, we observe that:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[R_A\right] \sigma_B^2}{Z_A + Z_B}&> \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[R_B\right]\sigma_A\sigma_B \mathbb{C}orr(R_A, R_B)}{Z_A + Z_B}\\
&\Updownarrow\\
\mathbb{E}\left[R_A\right] \sigma_B^2&> \mathbb{E}\left[R_B\right]\sigma_A\sigma_B \mathbb{C}orr(R_A, R_B)\\
&\Updownarrow\\
\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[R_A\right] \sigma_B^2}{\sigma_A}&> \mathbb{E}\left[R_B\right]\sigma_B \mathbb{C}orr(R_A, R_B)\\
&\Updownarrow\\
\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[R_A\right]}{\sigma_A}&> \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[R_B\right] \mathbb{C}orr(R_A, R_B)}{\sigma_B},\\
\end{align*}
where we in the second inequality uses the fact that the denominator is positive, and in the  third and fourth inequality have divided with $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B^2$ respecively.

Comment: How can we be sure that the denominator is greater than 0? Is there a mathematical formula to guarantee this?

Comment: So are you saying that we do not have a guarantee that the denominator is greater than 0? I can see that you derived the formula with the assumption that the denominator is greater than 0 and showed me several conditions(scenarios) to satisfy this assumption. But can you explicitly tell me if we have a guarantee that the denominator is greater than 0 or not, please?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the denominator is strictly positive. However, keep in mind that we need $W_a>0$ which only happens when $W_a = \frac{-A}{-B}=\frac{A}{B}>0$ (simplified). In the cases where the denominator is negative, we need to ensure that the numerator is negative aswell, in order to satisfy $W_a >0$. Thus the negations cancel out and the same calculations as stated above, follows.  There probably exists some combination of means, variances and correlations that will violate $W_a >0$. Also, I made a slight change in my answer, and thus the above comments have been changed. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here, I am specifically answering your question in the comments:

No, there is no guarantee that the denominator will be positive. For simplicity, assume that $r_f$=0 and that $E(R_A)=E(R_B)\frac{\sigma_A}{\sigma_B}\rho+\frac{c}{\sigma_b^2}$ with $c>0$. This level of $E(R_A)$ satisfies the condition in your question. Then,

$$
W_A=\frac{c}{c\left(1-\frac{\sigma_A}{\sigma_B}\rho\right)+E(R_B)\sigma_A^2\left(1-\rho^2\right)}
$$

and we can clearly have a situation where the optimal investment amount $W_A$ becomes negative, i.e. when

$$
c\left(1-\frac{\sigma_A}{\sigma_B}\rho\right)+E(R_B)\sigma_A^2\left(1-\rho^2\right)<0
$$

But if you start to play with the numbers, you will see that it may require some extreme combinations of $E(R_B), \sigma_A, \sigma_B, \rho, c$ in order for the quick-and-dirty rule not to work.

Comment: How did you come up with the equation related with $E(R_{A})$ after assuming that $r_{f} =0$ ?

Comment: That's an assumption: I just wanted to simplify the expressions a bit. The assumption satisfies your condition on a positive investment in asset $A$.